# Implementing a 'category' system with attributes

Tags: python, igraph

I have around 1000 'categories' which cover my Edges. I'm specifiying these categories using attributes:

`g.es[0]["$cat1"]=True`

One edge *can* belong to multiple categories.

The problem is, that this causes all of my other edges, even if they have nothing to do with category 1 to get an attribute `$cat1=None`.

So basically even if my edge is a part of a single category, it will have 999 other attributes such as `$catN=None`.

I need the ability to fetch each category (including all it's member nodes and edges) into a separate sub-graph. Right now I simply traverse over all the edges, seeing where `$catN = True`, and get those edges and nodes into a new graph.

1. Does this method as a whole look scalable? It seems a bit messy, since there might be a million nodes and ten thousand categories. That would mean each edge would store 2-3 `$catN = True` but thousands of redundant `$catN = None`.
2. If not, do you have any suggestions to implement this 'category' system better?
3. If it is the best that can be done, any suggestions for retrieving a particular category? Traversing ALL edges seems like a waste. I guess I can maintain a separate data structure with edge nos corresponding to each category. Would be a pain to maintain though.

Comment: Can you limit your post to one question please; and try to avoid open-ended opinionated ones like _"Does this method as a whole look scalable?"_

Comment: So you're saying I should've created 3 separate questions for this? They're all completely related to the problem I've described.

I agree about the open ended question, but I don't think it's wrong to expect that more experienced people here who've dealt with million node graphs with 1000 attributes might be able to give me some insight based on their experiences.

Comment: I don't know igraph so maybe that's not an option but can you attach a set of categories to edges? Something like `g.es[0]['categories'] = set(['$cat1'])` (and an empty set to edges which don't belong to any category).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this? I understand storing all categories in a set. But wouldn't that really solve nothing because instead of going through the `g.es[0]` dictionary keys, I'll have to go through the `g.es[0]['categories']` set to find out which category `g.es[0]` belongs to... Plus why would I need an empty set to edges which don't belong to any category?

Comment: If you don't store an empty set on edges not belonging to any category you'll need extra code to check this. The advantage over _n_ keys for _n_ overall categories in a dictionary at each edge is that the set just contains the actual categories of an egde. Checking if a category is in that set or even if a set of categories is a subset is efficient. I don't think you can avoid going through all edges to extract a subgraph for a given category if you can't build a mapping category→edges like suggested in @Tamás ' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to store the category of each edge as an edge attribute? If your graph will not be mutated (i.e. you will not delete edges from the graph), you can simply use an external Python dict that maps category IDs to edge IDs - then you can fetch the members of each category with a single dictionary lookup. If you also need to tell quickly which category an edge belongs to, you will also need the reverse mapping, so maybe it's best to create a separate "bidirectional mapping" class and maintain the two sides of the mapping separately:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class CategoryMapping(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.category_to_members = defaultdict(set)
        self.member_to_categories = defaultdict(set)

    def add(self, category, member):
        self.category_to_members[category].add(member)
        self.member_to_categories[member].add(category)

    def remove(self, category, member):
        self.category_to_members[category].discard(member)
        self.member_to_categories[member].discard(category)

    def categories_of(self, member):
        return self.member_to_categories[member]

    def members_of(self, category):
        return self.category_to_member[category]
```

**Edit**: If edges are sometimes removed from your graph, you can assign a unique ID for each edge in its `id` edge attribute and then use those IDs in the `CategoryMapping`. The only problem is that edge lookups by attribute is an O(n) operation where n is the number of edges. To mitigate this, you can create an edge ID-to-index mapping class as well. This class could have an `edges_removed()` method which you must call with the old IDs of the removed edges whenever you remove edges from your graph, and it should update the internal ID-to-index mapping accordingly. (Sadly, igraph does not have a special id-like attribute for edges, even though it treats the `name` attribute of vertex objects this way so you can achieve O(1) lookup of a vertex by name). You can make use of the fact that the index of edge *i* will become *i-k* after a removal iff there are *k* removed edges with an index smaller than *i* in the original graph.

Comment: This is a good idea but as you said it doesn't hold when edges are removed. Especially because igraph re-numbers the edge IDs once an edge is removed...

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible (but not really straightforward) solution for edge removals.